# grails neo4j how to define relationship and their properties

Tags: grails, plugins, neo4j

In grails-neo4j plug-in,how can i define relationship among nodes and properties of relationship.

I can define my nodes as domain classes but what if i want to connect nodes i.e. i want to map relationship of nodes in some form.

I found spring-neo4j framework which works well for this case and i can map relationship to java class but didn't find any grails compatibility layer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping domain classes as relationships is not yet supported in the Neo4j Grails plugin. I have this on my list of stuff to add.

You're right, Spring Data Neo4j already is capable of doing this. Be aware that Spring Data Neo4j and the Grails Neo4j plugin have nothing in common (aside that they use Neo4j to persist). The persistence layer is a completely separate code base.

Comment: have you provided any other way to define relationships?
I tried spring-data-neo4j,but could not be able to use with grails.

Comment: if a domain class is linked to another domain class of course a relationship will be used to model this. However it's not yet possible to model a domain class as a relationship, just like SDN's RelationshipEntity does. Consequently relationships currently won't have properties in the Grails plugin.

Answer (score 1):

the plugin doesn't map the domain classes directly to nodes or relations in neo4j. It uses its own structure, like:

```
root -> domainClass.name -> relation -> domain class instance
```

I'd recommend to define your domain classes as nodes, and the plugin should handle them properly. Another way: abandon the plugin >)

Comment: I have mapped my nodes as domain classes but i want to know for relationship,can i map relationship as a domain class or any other method is provided for that?

Comment: I don't think, it's possible: http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/neo4j/manual/guide/mapping.html

Comment: yes,i just want to make sure,otherwise i have option of spring-data-neo4j where i can easily map relationship to java class.

Comment: maybe it's worth writing your own mapper, like `GMongo` for `mongo-db`

Answer (score 0):

It is now much later than when this question was originally asked - 4 years later.  The plugin now supports Neo4j relationships being created as Grails domain classes and the relationship can have attributes.  However, constraints on these attributes do not work yet.  Below is the full code for a working, one-way relationship.

```
package neo4j.authentication.demo

import grails.neo4j.Relationship
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class BelongsTo implements Relationship<Car, Owner> {

    String sinceWhen

    String toString() {
        sinceWhen
    }
}
```